# Application shrinks when keyboard is on

Tags: app-inventor

I am using Amazon Fire 10 HD tablets to teach MIT App inventor. When I start typing in a text box keyboard pops up as expected. But instead of covering the bottom part of the screen it pushes the application (keeping the ratio) to top and shrinks it to fit the height left from the keyboard. 
Normally you would expect the on screen keyboard to be floating on the application but this is not the same

Answer (score 0):

use Sizing = Responsive instead of Fixed in your Screen settings